# How to handle estimate gas cost error?

Tags: metamask, javascript, gas-estimate, error

I am programming a button for a transaction which shall only appear if the transaction is possible. Therefore, I am using the following code

```
contract.methods.function(parameters)
  .estimateGas({...},(error,result) =>
  {
    if(!error)
    {
      \\ show button
    }
    else
    {...}
  })
```

However, there is always a MetaMask error in my javascript console if the transaction would fail. Is there a way to catch this error? I just do not want it to appear in the console.

[image]

Comment: Post the actual ode please (Solidity code of the function, and Javascript code of the arguments that you are passing to `estimateGas`).

Comment: Why do you care about the message appearing in the console?

Comment: It seems a bit weird to me that an error message pops up only because the transaction is estimated to fail. Hence, I would like to handle this message. I guess there should be a simple JS trick to catch it but everything I tried still was leading to the error message. I tried `try{await contract.meth...}catch(err){\\ log err}` but it would then show the message of `err` plus the same error message of MetaMask.